# In my rails application,when I tried to add git it's giving me the following error:

Tags: git

This is what is happening when I add git to my application:

```
sawanrasool:~/workspace $ git add -A
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: _Sidenote:_ never ever do `git add -A`, inspect files you are adding, otherwise sooner or later you’ll find yourself recovering a repo.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `git init` first?

I would also recommend following a simple tutorial (at first) like this one:
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Answer (score 0):

That's not the command to 'add git'. That's the command to stage or 'add' files, namely looking at the working tree and adding new or modified files to your commit.

You can try doing `git init`, but first check that you're in the folder with the git repository. For rails apps, this is usually the parent folder of the app, config, db sub folders.